# How to bind an application's port to a remote host with public IP?

Tags: networking, server

I have redis server running on one server. By default it listens to port 6379. When I open the redis conf file I see something like this

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

Since my redis client resides on another remote server which is not in the same network as this, I need to bind this to the public IP of the redis client. Something like this

```
bind 54.23.x.x
```

And I don't want to specify `bind 0.0.0.0`. When I try that and restart redis server, I get the following error

```
bind : cannot assign requested address
```

In general how do I bind an application to a specific public IP ?

Comment: On the server, you need to bind to its own IP address, not that of the client. 'Bind' means 'listen on', not 'listen to'.

Comment: I tried to give server's public IP address too. It didn't work.